# .NET Framework 3.5 wont install on VISTA 32bit

Tags: .net-3.5, windows-vista, frameworks

Running VISTA 32bit.

I am trying to install c# Visual Express 2008 - but it requires .NET 3.5. One of the prerequisites during the install is .NET 3.5 ... it attempts to install it but fails, with no real error message.

So I downloaded .NET 3.5 standalone from MS website and tried that.Again it fails with the error

> [10/17/08,23:17:07] WapUI: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft .NET Framework 3.0SP1 (CBS) is not installed.
>   [10/17/08,23:50:55] Microsoft .NET Framework 3.0SP1 (CBS): [2] Error: Installation failed for component Microsoft .NET Framework 3.0SP1 (CBS). MSI returned error code 34

I currently have c# Express edition 2005 installed. But everything I read says that I can have these two applications installed together. I believe that 2005 runs Framework 2.0. 2005 express edition works fine. - its just the 2008 edition im having problems installed the .NET 3.5 with ....

any ideas ? thanks

Comment: This isn't really a tech support forum, and that isn't really a programming question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

.NET Framework 3.0 is a component that is released together with Windows Vista. In order to get SP1 of .NET Framework 3.0, you have to install **Windows Vista SP1**. The stand-alone SP1 installer for .NET Framework 3.0 is meant for operating systems that do not have it natively.

Comment: this turned out to be my issue. I was installing it without Vista SP1. After 2 hours of updating - just to geto the SP1 - .. after SP1 was installed 3.5 installed without any issues. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

It's a little odd that it won't automatically install .NET 3.0 and SP1 for you.  It appears that the error is that it isn't able to install .NET 3.0 (a pre-requisite for 3.5).  Perhaps you could try doing it manually?  (Also, ensure that you don't have pre-release versions installed.)

Install .NET 3.0 using the link below.

[.NET 3.0 Redistributable Package](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=10CC340B-F857-4A14-83F5-25634C3BF043&displaylang=en)

Then, follow up with .NET 3.0 SP1 using the link below.

[.Net 3.0 Service Pack 1](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=EC2CA85D-B255-4425-9E65-1E88A0BDB72A&displaylang=en)

After that, try running the installation, again.  If it still fails, you could try installing .NET 3.5 SP1 manually, as well.

[.NET 3.5 Redistributable Package](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=333325FD-AE52-4E35-B531-508D977D32A6&displaylang=en)

[.NET 3.5 Service Pack 1](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=AB99342F-5D1A-413D-8319-81DA479AB0D7&displaylang=en)

Comment: ok O tried the first link. Started installing and it says - 

You must use "Turn Windows features on or off" in the control panel to install or configure .NET Framework 2.0 

WHERE in the control panel do I find this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever installed any of the pre-release versions of 3.0 or 3.5?  I had a lot of trouble installing 3.5 until I realized that I had installed a CTP of WPF.  Go through all of your Microsoft and .NET installs in Add/Remove programs and make sure that you don't have any pre-release versions.

Answer (score 0):

Laila -

[msdn](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxsetup/thread/6f25986f-ff3c-4eef-96b0-91a8502791d3/)

Shows someone with the same error message, in the end it was because they had windows update service turned off. You may wish to try that.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, I've been at this for a while now, too. And going in circles. "msdn" above probably has the key to this. However, go out and google on turning on windows update. I have tried, and I've found a reputable forum with another MS techie, with instructions for using command line instructions to rename this and delete that and yadda... scared to death to DO that, as this is a primary work machine. Why on earth does MS make all of this so hard? I have never, in 20 years of computing, run into the messes that Vista has made for us. I cannot turn on Windows Update. And I cannot get the .NET stuff installed, for the very things spoken of, in this forum. What I need is .NET 3.5. But have run into the same slew of "errors" talked about here. Stuck. MS has been daily agony with Vista. I thought I'd adjusted to most of the intracicies, and have even been very satisfied... until coming up against this with .NET. WHY isn't all of the ready to go with purchase of a machine? I do not remember EVER setting the Windows Update to not update... so all of this is a tricky thorn in the side.

Answer (score 0):

This thread is old but thought I would add something

Check that you do not have a C++ Redist installed, if so, uninstal and try again. Worked for me.